# To trace the parent control

Tags: c#, .net

I want to trace all the parent controls of a control
(e.g) if i have a form which contains panel which in turn contains another panel which contains button,
i want to trace all the parents(form,panel,panel) from button
how to do that?

Comment: Would you consider to accept some answers to your previous questions first? Otherwise, people will be disinclined to answer your new questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
private List<Control> FindParentList(Control control)
{
    List<Control> retVal = new List<Control>();
    Control c = control;
    while (c.Parent != null)
    {
        Control parent = c.Parent;
        retVal.Add(parent);
        c = parent;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

And to call the method use

```
List<Control> parentList = FindParentList(button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The property *Parent* (inherited on every control from Control.Parent) provides access to the parent control.  One can follow these references all the way up to the top-level Form.